# AWS Sagemaker Neural Topic Model

Tags: amazon-web-services, neural-network, amazon-sagemaker

What is underlying algorithm for Sagemaker's [Neural Topic Model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ntm.html)? I have hard time googling for details, and the documentation doesn't mention any paper.

Googling for 'neural topic model' doesn't exactly answer my question, since a couple of methods seems to be called that.

Comment: To quickly find the solution: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06038.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like AWS SageMaker team answered the question, 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=270493&tstart=0